# Tower property of joint distribution $E_{X,Y}[XY]$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I understand the classic version $E_X[X] = E_{Z}[E_{X|Z}[X|Z]]$.

My question relates to if $E_{(X,Y)}[XY] = E_X[E_{Y|X}[XY|X]]$ holds.

Suppose we are working with discrete random variables. My thought process:

$$
\begin{align}
\text{E}_{(X,Y)}[XY]&= \sum_{x,y} x\text{ }y\text{ } \text{Pr}(X = x,Y = y)\\
&= \sum_{x,y} x\text{ }y\text{ } \text{Pr}(Y = y | X = x) \text{ }\text{Pr}(X = x)\\
&= \sum_{x,y}x \left( y \text{ }\text{Pr}(Y = y | X = x) \right)\text{ }\text{Pr}(X = x)\\
&= \sum_{x}x\left( \sum_{y }y \text{ }\text{Pr}(Y = y | X = x) \right)\text{Pr}(X = x)\\
&= \sum_{x}x \text{ }\text{E}_{Y|X=x}[Y|X=x]\text{ }\text{Pr}(X = x)\\
&= \sum_{x}x \text{ }g(x)\text{ }\text{Pr}(X = x)\\
&= E_X[g(X)]\quad (\text{where }g(t) = \text{E}_{Y|X=x}[Y|X=t)\\
&= E_X[\text{E}_{Y|X}[Y|X]]
\end{align}
$$

Is above correct? One can also derive in the similar way for continuous random variables right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is almost completely correct. You just have a small mistake at the end. Recall, for any function $h$, that
$$
\sum_x h(x)Pr(X=x)=E[h(X)]
$$
Applying this to the function $h(x)=x\;g(x)$, your last couple of lines should be
$$
\begin{align}
E_{(X,Y)}[XY]
&=\cdots
\\&= \sum_x x \,g(x)\,Pr(X=x)
\\&= E[Xg(X)]
\\&= E[X\; E_{Y\mid X}[Y\mid X]]
\\&= E[E_{Y\mid X}[XY\mid X]]
\end{align}
$$
The last equation is a basic property of conditional expectation. When conditioning on $X$, any function of $X$ behaves like a constant, so you can pull the $X$ inside the conditional expectation.

As you mentioned, the same proof works when $X,Y$ are jointly continuous, by replacing summations with integrals.